# Delete file from system location with app-scoped security bookmark

Tags: macos, filesystems, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I've got an OS X App where I request app-scoped security bookmarks from the user using an `NSOpenPanel` - this works great.

Now I want to delete the file as well - this works for ALL files except for those stored in system locations, e.g. `/private/var/log`. Even though the user granted me a (not stale) security bookmark.

Is there any entitlement that allows me to delete user-selected files from those locations?

Just for reference, the following entitlements are set:

`<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
    <array>
        <string>/.Trash</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>`

Cheers!

Comment: I don't have a solution from the top of my head but I just wanted to hint that I have been in a "never ending" discussion with the Review Team about temporary-exception — they basically don't want people to use them anymore. Furthermore, thanks for reminding me the security bookmarks. I must look into that again asap. I'll ask around if someone has a solution for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the files in system locations belong to user `root` and no one else has write permission. In order to delete such files, they need to have the appropriate permissions set. You can check this using terminal:

```
cd /private/var/log
ls -la
```

Just because your app has permission by sandbox doesn't mean it has permission by filesystem to write and remove. Sorry to say.

Comment: The files are rw-r--r-- with $(whoami):staff permissions, so the current user is the owner. Should work from that perspective, as rm from the terminal works without problems, too.

Comment: sadly it's a permission error after all. chmod'ing the enclosing folder to go+w makes the original app work. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is access to the file's (parent) directory, as it's the directory that is modified when a file is deleted.

I assume you can do this using the same permission-granting mechanism you currently use.

Of course the user themselves don't have read/write access to all the files in the system, so that will limit the ability to delete system files.  If you wanted to delete those then you need to implement privilege escalation.

Comment: I'll try that and will report back if it works properly. thanks!